# Samsung S6 Active will not boot; AP, ROM flash succeeds (bootloader flash fails); then BL flash works, but the device still won't boot

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, boot-loop, bootloader

I am having trouble with my S6 Active. It has been stuck in a boot loop for a week now. It was running stock beforehand. I flashed a stock AT&T Nougat ROM with Odin. The AP, CP, and CSC all successfully flash but it is still stuck on the Samsung logo screen when it boots. Here is the log:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> Total Binary size: 4539 M
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Set PIT file..
<ID:0/003> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!
<ID:0/003> Erase...
<ID:0/003> ERASE_SECTOR: 1197824
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> ERASE_OK
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> boot.img
<ID:0/003> recovery.img
<ID:0/003> system.img
<ID:0/003> userdata.img
<ID:0/003> modem.bin
<ID:0/003> Transmission Complete.. 
<ID:0/003> Now Writing.. Please wait about 2 minutes
<ID:0/003> Receive Response from boot-loader
<ID:0/003> cache.img
<ID:0/003> RQT_CLOSE !!
<ID:0/003> RES OK !!
<ID:0/003> Removed!!
<ID:0/003> Remain Port ....  0 
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 1 / failed 0)
```

If I try to flash the Bootloader, and it fails. I receive the following:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> Total Binary size: 4 M
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Erase...
<ID:0/003> ERASE_SECTOR: 1197824
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> ERASE_OK
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> sboot.bin
<ID:0/003> FAIL!
<ID:0/003> 
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Is the bootloader the issue or is it just failing because it's bootloader locked? Is there anything I can try to get it to boot?

For reference, the ROM I am using is found [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/galaxy-s6-active/g890a-stock-att-odin-nougat-7-0-firmware-t3611772):

```
AP_G890AUCU6DQD1_CL10950877_QB13102601_REV02_user_ low_ship_meta.tar
BL_G890AUCU6DQD1_CL10950877_QB13102601_REV02_user_ low_ship.tar
CP_G890AUCU6DQD1_CP6129305_CL10950877_QB13102601_R EV02_user_low_ship.tar
CSC_ATT_G890AATT6DQD1_CL10950877_QB13102601_REV02_ user_low_ship.tar
```

I purchased this phone secondhand. I do not know if the prior user flashed it.

**UPDATE**: I was able to flash the most current firmware onto the device.

```
Model: Samsung Galaxy S6 Active SM-G890A 
OS Version: Android Nougat V7.0
PDA/AP Version: G890AUCS7DRF2 
MODEM/CP Version: G890AUCS7DRF2 
CSC Version: G890AATT7DRF2 
Region: USA AT&T
Security Patch Level : 2018-07-03
```

I flashed the BL, AP, CP, CSC, and used the .pit file, and everything went smoothly:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> Total Binary size: 4644 M
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Set PIT file..
<ID:0/003> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!
<ID:0/003> Erase...
<ID:0/003> ERASE_SECTOR: 1197824
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> ERASE_OK
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> sboot.bin
<ID:0/003> param.bin
<ID:0/003> cm.bin
<ID:0/003> boot.img
<ID:0/003> recovery.img
<ID:0/003> system.img
<ID:0/003> userdata.img
<ID:0/003> modem.bin
<ID:0/003> Transmission Complete.. 
<ID:0/003> Now Writing.. Please wait about 2 minutes
<ID:0/003> Receive Response from boot-loader
<ID:0/003> cache.img
<ID:0/003> RQT_CLOSE !!
<ID:0/003> RES OK !!
<ID:0/003> Removed!!
<ID:0/003> Remain Port ....  0 
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 1 / failed 0
```

HOWEVER, the device is still stuck on the Samsung logo when it boots. I'm not sure what else I can do at this point. It's out of warranty and Samsung wants $70 to fix it.

Comment: Was your device on Oreo or 7.1 and you flashed ROM of earlier version?  Samsung often prevents this. Also check if the ROM is **exactly** for your device variant

Comment: I'm unsure of Android on it beforehand. I do know it was an AT&T S6 Active (SM-G890A) and the rom I'm using is stock AT&T Nougat for SM-G890A. It does not look like Samsung ever updated the S6 Active to Oreo (looks like 7.0 was the latest and the "device is not eligible" for Oreo). There are some possible older firmwares I could try, but the downloads are all locked behind RapidGator (ugh). 

The Nougat firmware flashes fine except for the BL. I don't know if that's the core of the issue - why it won't boot past the Samsung logo - or if that's unrelated to the boot issue. 

Thanks!

Comment: It could well be bootloader related as Samsung often doesn't permit downgrading of bootloaders. Download the latest ROM for sammobiles dot Com and check

Comment: Unfortuantely, sammobile does not have any roms for SM-G890A. I was able to get the most recent rom flashed on it including the bootloader (see update in post), and it still doesn't work. So not I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: That's very strange. And unfortunate. Wait for a while - may be somebody can pitch in.

Comment: Try the latest Odin version or the version claimed compatible with your device

Answer (score 0):

I bought a firmware for US$3 from [G890AUCS7DRF2_G890AATT7DRF2_V7.0_Repair_Firmware_4Files_( USA AT&T )](https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=file&id=92041). It worked flawlessly. I could go back to Android 6.0 and had the phone labeled as S6 Edge, 16 GB storage, no baseband, etc.

I uploaded the following file to Google Drive: [G890AUCS7DRF2_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship_meta](https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1t_O2ZmJm7GF9nji9QvACFAdxV0m7E6bo&export=download). It is the firmware for Samsung Galaxy S6 Active (G890A) to fix boot or missing baseband.

Comment: Can you provide the instructions on flashing it?

Comment: @JoeMunden Wow, after trying 6 different SM-G890A ROMs, the one you listed worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, they recommended you use the default Odin3 options. I previously botched a downgrade to 6.0 and had a partial 6.0 bootloader working (always failed after sboot.bin using different ROMs). For me, I turned on `Nand Erase` and `Re-Partition` with a `PIT file` that I extracted from the CSV file using 7.zip.

Thanks to Joe Munden for linking the correct file.
[G890AUCS7DRF2_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship_meta](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t_O2ZmJm7GF9nji9QvACFAdxV0m7E6bo/view)

[image: Log]
[image: Options]
[image: Pit]

G890AUCS7DRF2_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship_meta.zip :

- AP_G890AUCS7DRF2_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship_meta.tar.md5
- BL_G890AUCS7DRF2_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship.tar.md5
- CP_G890AUCS7DRF2_CP9924223_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship.tar.md5
- CSC_ATT_G890AATT7DRF2_CL12599862_QB18539350_REV02_user_low_ship.tar.md5

  - (PIT file MARINELTE_USA_ATT.pit inside the CSC file)